# Generate a dynamic partialview within the controller MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to generate a dynamic form using MVC.
I'm planning to create the HTML code within the Action of a Controller(based on database values) and pass it to the View as a Partialview.
To accomplish this task I need to create a dynamic view inside the Action. So I could add all the html codes within that and pass it to the view as a Partialview.
Is there any way to do that ?

Or
Is there any other way in MVC to dynamically generate html elements ?

Comment: Can you give more details or examples of what the disered result is? Add your controller and partial view code also.

Comment: you can use templating engine like mustache http://mustache.github.io/

Comment: "Dynamic" is a buzzword. Explain what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In that action, you can return `html` contents created on the fly. Just use `Content()` as bellows

```
return Content("<form><input value='"+valueFromDb+"'/>...</form>");
```

but this is not a good practice so, you need to create a partial view and then return it using

```
//var modelFromDb=db.Table.FirstOrDefault();
 return PartialView("MyPartial",modelFromDb);
```

**EDITS:** To generate code for your partial, you need to right click in your controller action and choose **Add View** type **MyPartial** as View name and then check the **Add Strongly Typed View** ... you will need to precise the model class and the template to be used (list,delete,edit,create or empty)

Comment: But in the second way "MyPartial" is an empty view. I need to generate the code required for that view in server side.Is there anyway to do that ?

Comment: see my edits: `To generate code for your partial, you need to right click in your controller action and choose Add View type MyPartial as View name and then check the Add Strongly Typed View ... you will need to precise the model class and the template to be used (list,delete,edit,create or empty)`

Comment: Well maybe the way I presented the question doesnt show my real requirement. For example , there are 100's of records in db. Depending on the values of the DB the partial view changes , like in one instance it's 2 textboxes , 1 radio button and 3 checkboxes. In another instance it's 4 textboxes , 3 radio buttons and 2 checkboxes and like wise. So I can't hard code the model and the view. I need to dynamically generate the html(razor) code requiered for the view and then put it to the Partialview , and display it within a div element in a the parent view. So is there anyway , that I can do ....

Comment: that within an action or even within a script  ?

Comment: Okay it's clear @CibaZag: you'd inspect your different models in order to find similarities and then create a generic-model so you don't care the db returned model value. I suggest you edit your question in order to provide sample models values so I will help you write a generic model for them

Answer (score 0):

I don't think generating code in controller is a good idea, things will get messy.

If you are saving the fields in the database, you must be saving a type against each field.

**Example:**

```
Field Types Table

TypeId      Name
1           TextBox
2           DropDown


Fields Table

FieldId        TypeId (FK)    IsEdit    FormId (FK)       Style
1                1               1          1            color: red
2                2               1          1              NULL
```

When reading from database you can convert these to a list of fields

```
public class Field
{
// Common Properties
public string Style {get;set;}
public int    TypeId {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;

}
```

then for each type you have in DB you can create a class and derive from Field

```
public class DropDown : Field
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Values {get;set;}
}

public class TextBox : Field
{
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Then when reading from database pass each through a Factory class

// READ from DB

```
var model = new List<Field>();

var fields = dbContext.Fields.Where(s => s.FormId == 1);

foreach(var field in fields){

model.Add(FieldFactory(field));

}
```

// PASS THROUGH FACTORY

```
public Field FieldFactory(Form form){

switch(field.TypeId)
{
     case 1: // Textbox --> you can use enum
     return new TextBox(SET_VALUES);

}

}
```

Then create a partial View e.g. `form.cshtml`, pass list of field as model

```
return PartialView("form", new List<Field>());
```

Then handle the field type in `form.cshtml`

```
@model List<Field>

@foreach(var field in Model){

switch(field.TypeId){

case 1: // TextBox
@Html.Partial("TextBox", (TextBox)field)
break;

case 2:
@Html.Partial("DropDown", (DropDown)field)
break;


}
}
```

Create a partial view for each field type:

TextBox.cshtml:

```
@model TextBox

<input type ="text" name = "@Model.Name" stlye ="@Model.Style" value = "@Model.Value" />
```

DropDown.cshtml

```
@model DropDown

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FieldId, new SelectList(Model.Values, "Value", "Key")
```

With this method you add JavaScript and jQuery code to each field PartialView.